# Merge objects in array into single one

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects as following:

```
arr = [  
    {  
        totalPrice:{  
            value:5,
            currencyId:0
        }
    },
    {  
        totalPrice:{  
            value:1,
            currencyId:0
        }
    },
    {  
        totalPrice:{  
            value:6,
            currencyId:0
        }
    }
]
```

What I'm trying to do is to get one single object (totalPrice) that will contain the sum of value, if all totalPrice objects have the same currencyId.

First step was to determine if all the totalPrice objects have the same currencyId:

```
var canBeMerged = arr.every(l => l.totalPrice.currencyId === arr[0].totalPrice.currencyId);
```

Then:

```
var merged = null;

if(canBeMerged){
    var valueSum = 0;

    for (var k=0; k<arr.length; k++) {
      valueSum += arr[k].totalPrice.value;
    }
      merged = {value: valueSum, currencyId: arr[0].totalPrice.currencyId}
}
```

Is there a way to do all of this in a single way? I think reduce function would do that but I cannot figure out how to do it.

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: What's the expected output?

Comment: What if there is another object with `currencyId:1`

Comment: "Is there a way to do all of this in a single way?" Why? Your code is readable & maintainable. I don't see any need for improvement (except that `var` that leaks from it's block scope)

Comment: @JackBashford it's the merged variable

Comment: @MaheerAli in htis case canBeMerged would be false, I have modified my solution so it looks clear

Comment: @JonasWilms The thing is that every function which is not supported by all the browsers, I mentioned the reduce function since we have a modified version of it in our intern framework that will support all the browsers, since the solution can be done using the native reduce function, I'm trying to do that.

Comment: `.every` and `.reduce` were both introduced with ES5, if an engine supports one it also supports the other. I highly recommend using a transpiler though (e.g. https://babeljs.io)

Comment: @JonasWilms `every` and `reduce` are both ES5. But arrow functions are indeed ES2015. So a transpilation is required for elder browsers.

Comment: @yury Oh right. My bad.

Comment: @JonasWilms Thanks, I already know about the transpiler but  I cannot use, in the framework I'm using there is a `.reduce` function similar to the native one that also supports the older browsers, but we don't have the same for `.every`

Comment: `function every(array, callback) { for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) { if(!callback(array[i], i)) return false; } return true; }`

Answer (score 0):

```
let merged = {
  value: arr.
    filter(e => e.totalPrice.currencyId === arr[0].totalPrice.currencyId).
    reduce((a, b) => a + b.totalPrice.value, 0),
  currencyId: arr[0].totalPrice.currencyId
};
```

We start by filtering out all the entries of the `arr` array where the property `totalPrice.currencyId` does not match the same property of the first entry in the `arr` array using `filter`. `filter` returns a new array of filtered items. We can chain `reduce` to sum up the values in this filtered array.

Comment: The tricky part in this question is the "can be merged" condition.

Comment: In this case if I have for example the currencyId for the second object is 1, I will still get a merge of the first and the third objects, which is suppose to be null.

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding the question. This does what you're doing in 1 go.

Answer (score 0):

This uses an object to accumulate the value of each `currencyId`.

```
let merge = arr => {
  d = {};
  arr.forEach(a => d[a.totalPrice.currencyId] = (d[a.totalPrice.currencyId] ? d[a.totalPrice.currencyId] : 0) + a.totalPrice.value);
  return Object.entries(d).map(([k, i]) => ({ value: i, currencyId: parseInt(k) }));
}
```

Example:

```
>> arr = [  
        {  
            totalPrice:{  
                value:5,
                currencyId:0
            }
        },
        {  
            totalPrice:{  
                value:1,
                currencyId:0
            }
        },
        {  
            totalPrice:{  
                value:6,
                currencyId:0
            }
        }
    ]

>> merge(arr)
 [{ value:12, currencyId:0 }]

>> arr = [  
        {  
            totalPrice:{  
                value:5,
                currencyId:0
            }
        },
        {  
            totalPrice:{  
                value:1,
                currencyId:1
            }
        },
        {  
            totalPrice:{  
                value:6,
                currencyId:0
            }
        }
    ]

>> merge(arr)
 [{ value:11, currencyId:0 }, { value:1, currencyId:1 }]
```

Comment: Thanks, this solution looks great, but it will merge all objects that have the same currencyId, for me I only want to merge all objects if only they have the same currencyId, otherwise nothing will happen.

Comment: Oh, okay, now I get it. :)

Answer (score -1):

Here's an example in the functional style:

```js
pipe = (...fns) => obj => fns.reduce((r, f) => r === null ? null : f(r), obj);
ifAll = fn => a => a.every(fn) ? a : null;
pick = prop => a => a.map(x => x[prop]);
sum = a => a.reduce((x, y) => x + y, 0);

//

sumCurr = pipe(
    pick('totalPrice'),
    ifAll(x => x.currencyId === 0),
    pick('value'),
    sum,
);

//

arr = [
    {
        totalPrice:{
            value:5,
            currencyId:0
        }
    },
    {
        totalPrice:{
            value:1,
            currencyId:0
        }
    },
    {
        totalPrice:{
            value:6,
            currencyId:0
        }
    }
]

console.log(sumCurr(arr))
```

Although I'd actually use a library like lodash or ramda, that already provide this kind of stuff.

If your target doesn't support `every` and `some`, they are easily expressed with `reduce`:

```
 every = (a, f) => a.reduce((r, x) => r && f(x), true);
 some  = (a, f) => a.reduce((r, x) => r || f(x), false);
```

Comment: Congrats, you achieved the same result as the OP with a far more complex solution.

Comment: @JonasWilms: I find my function easier to read that the OP's code, the supporting framework (`pipe` etc) should be of course provided by a lib (a stock one or your own).

Comment: You might find it easier, the OP probably won't (not my downvote though)